# Buffers that are neither active nor hidden

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, help-system, hidden-buffers

Both `:ls` and `:buffers` display a list with buffer information, giving indicators for each buffer. For example, `#` means the alternate buffer, and `%` means the current buffer. The meaning of each indicator is explained in `:h :ls` or `:h :buffers`. For `a` and `h`, it says:

```
    a     an active buffer: it is loaded and visible
    h     a hidden buffer: It is loaded, but currently not
              displayed in a window |hidden-buffer|
```

From this description, I would imagine that every buffer must be either active or hidden, since every buffer must be either shown or not shown. However, I often encounter buffers that don't have any of the two indicators. For example, buffer 8 in my current `:ls` list doesn't have any of the two:

```
:ls
  2 #h   "Silent commands.wiki"         line 35
  8      "~/repos/dotvim/vimrc"         line 0
 11 %a   "~/repos/wiki/diary/2021-03-20.wiki" line 47
```

How is this possible? Am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll find more details under `:h active-buffer` and the sections that follow...

```
                            *active-buffer*
active:   The buffer is displayed in a window.  If there is a file for this
      buffer, it has been read into the buffer.

                            *hidden-buffer*
hidden:   The buffer is not displayed.  If there is a file for this buffer, it
      has been read into the buffer.  Otherwise it's the same as an active
      buffer, you just can't see it.

                            *inactive-buffer*
inactive: The buffer is not displayed and does not contain anything.
```

So you're wondering about the the "inactive" windows. This table may help.

```
state       displayed   loaded      ":buffers" 
             in window               shows      
active        yes        yes          'a'
hidden        no         yes          'h'
inactive      no         no       ' '
```

Here's an easy way to produce one:

1. Start vim with a file
2. Tell vim to add another file to the buffer list: `:badd /some/other/file`
3. `:ls`

`:badd` does not load the file it just queues it up to be loaded when you switch to it with, for example, `:bnext`.

It can't be active since it's not visible. It can't be active *or* hidden since it hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely quick reply. Is there a way to programmatically determine whether a buffer is active, hidden or inactive? I can distinguish between active and hidden/inactive with `bufwinnr()`, since this function returns `-1` when the buffer is not active. But I don't know any way to distinguish hidden from inactive.

Comment: I know you can test whether a buffer is _loaded_ with `:echo bufloaded("/some/file")`. There's also `buflisted()` and `bufexists()`. Between all those you can get a pretty clear picture, I think. I'll see if I can narrow the focus down even more than that. Oh, yeah, there's also `getbufinfo()` which returns a whole bunch of info....that may be the ticket.

Comment: Yeah, look into `getbufinfo()`...it has the same info as the other three I listed and a lot more.

Comment: Thank you. I think that function does the job already, no need to narrow it down more. You can first check whether a buffer is visible with `bufwinnr()`. If it is not, then it must be either hidden or not loaded. Then you can do a second check with `bufloaded()`. If it is loaded, it is hidden, and if it is not loaded, it is not loaded. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. `getbufinfo()` will get you the info you want with a single func call, FYI.

Comment: This happens a lot when loading sessions with lots of buffers but only a few files open, too.